# Camel jetty http redirect

Tags: apache-camel, karaf

I m using karaf with camel (last version for each)

I try to expose a servlet and redirect to www.google.fr like this

```
    RouteDefinition routeDefinition2 = from("servlet:google?matchOnUriPrefix=true").id("reverseProxyRoute");
        routeDefinition2
        .to("http://www.google.fr?bridgeEndpoint=true&traceEnabled=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false&proxyHost=localhost&proxyPort=3128")
```

Route is correctly expose and i can reach the servlet but when i do :

```
http://localhost:8181/camel-example-servlet-rest-blueprint/rest/google
```

google page is show but when i launch a search my url become :

```
http://localhost:8181/search?safe=active&ei=lSYSXMLkIsa1kwWgsIKABg&q=camel+http
```

so i got 404 not found.

if i rewrite manually the url to have :

```
http://localhost:8181/camel-example-servlet-rest-blueprint/rest/google/search?safe=active&ei=cCYSXKDKMNG5kwWT77bYDQ&q=camel+http
```

it work

my question is how can i tell my route to don't remove

```
camel-example-servlet-rest-blueprint/rest/google/
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The removal of the URL part is the **behavior of the Google page**.

The HTML code of the search form is

```
<form ... action="/search" ...
```

Therefore if you submit the form, your browser is sent to `/search` and you get the response from this URL.

To do what you want you would have to offer your own search page to the users. This search page would submit the search terms to your application, you would have to do a Google search with it and return the results back to the user (on your own result page).